# Repast restart issue

Tags: java

I'm developing an artificial intelligent program to explore a given space for resources.

I'd like to run multiple scenarios in order to collect data and output to a file.

I used the "multiple runs" option in the gui and i do `stop()` when one module run is finished (all the resources have been explored). The problem is when It runs the model a second turn, it doesn't work properly.

What I mean is that after running once I always need to kill the application by exiting because the restart option doesn't work properly.

Is there anything that "restart" forgets to do? Because if I exit the application and run it again it works perfectly

Edited so it's more clear:

I use the [Repast](http://repast.sourceforge.net/) platform in order to simulate an exploration to Mars. I have 3 kinds of agents, scouting, digging and transporting. They communicate among them to schedule tasks and other things.

The first time I run the simulation everything runs smoothly. And when all the mineral resources of the planet have been explored I restart the model and try again so I can collect data.

The problem is, when I use the "restart" option the Simulation doesn't run well. But if I exit (not restart) and run it again it works fine.

What I'd like to know is if the restart option of Repast GUI misses any steps..

Thanks in advance

PS: If you guys think that it's absolutely necessary I can post some code...but the project is quite big

Comment: Can you clarify things a bit?

Comment: Without some code I doubt you will get good answers.

Comment: I have no idea what Repast is, so I'm probably just blowing smoke... but... does your code have to be tied to the GUI ? If you want to run several different simulations using the same initial conditions, and then collect data on the results, it might make sense to just do it behind the scenes, on a worker thread. But, like I said, I probably don't know what I'm talking about.

Comment: Added link; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't use Thread.stop() method. It is deprecated. Thread.stop is being deprecated because it is inherently unsafe. Stopping a thread causes it to unlock all the monitors that it has locked. (The monitors are unlocked as the ThreadDeath exception propagates up the stack.) If any of the objects previously protected by these monitors was in an inconsistent state, other threads might view these objects in an inconsistent state. Such objects are said to be damaged. Threads operating on damaged objects can behave arbitrarily, either obviously or not. Unlike other unchecked exceptions, ThreadDeath kills threads silently; thus, the user has no warning that the program may be corrupted. The corruption can manifest itself at an unpredictable time after the damage occurs. Substitute any use of Thread.stop with code that provides for a gentler termination.

http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/805-4031/6j3qv1of1?a=view

1. Consider thread stopping either via Thread.interrupt() or via setting cancel flag. Look at Java Concurrency in Practice, Section 7.1. Task Cancellation.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but when I use Thread.CurrentThread.interrupt() repast simply ignores it...at least it doesn't happen anything. 
I'm going to try running a bunch in batch mode.
Thanks

Comment: interrupt() does not actually interrupts thread it only requests for interruption. So you should consider interruption policy for the thread if you have access to its run() method.